# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null error when assign forien key value?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to assign foreign key value. foreign key is `user_id` in `p_members` table. The original key is userId in `all_users` table. But when I try to do that occur following error.

I create separate two table to get the user details and get `p-member` details.

I'm a beginner in Laravel.

**Error:**

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into `p_members` (`addNo`, `addStreet`,
>   `addCity`, `intentToJoin`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (qwertfgyhj, ertfyguhj, erdftgyhuj, ertfgyhjk, , 2018-09-06
>   16:38:19, 2018-09-06 16:38:19))

**My controller is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\allUser;
use App\ORFOL;
use App\pMember;

class userController extends Controller
{
    public function storeUsers(Request $request){
            $table1=new allUser();


            $table1->nameWithInitials = $request->input('name');
            $table1->callingName      = $request->input('callingName');
            $table1->email            = $request->input('email');
            $table1->NIC              = $request->input('nic');
            $table1->contactNo        = $request->input('contactNo');
            $table1->password         = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
            $table1->type             = $request->input('type');

            $table1->save();


        if($request->input('type') == 'P-Member'){
            $table2=new pMember();

            $table2->addNo            = $request->input('addNo');
            $table2->addStreet        = $request->input('addStreet');
            $table2->addCity          = $request->input('addCity');
            $table2->intentToJoin     = $request->input('intentToJoin');

            $table2->user_id          = $table1->userId;

            $table2->save();
            return view('familyMember');

        }

        if(($request->input('type')) =='OR-FOL' ){
            $table3=new ORFOL();

            $table3->region           = $request->input('region');
            $table3->user_id          = $table1->userId;

            $table3->save();

        }

        if(($request->input('type')) =='' ){
            $table3=new ORFOL();

            $table3->region           = $request->input('region');
            $table2->user_id          = $table1->userId;

            $table3->save();

        }


        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: If the primary key for `allUser` is `id`, then you need to use `$table2->user_id          = $table1->id;`. If it's supposed to be `userId`, you need to make sure that's set as the primary key in `allUser`.

Comment: I already do that.

Comment: Do which part? What's the schema for `allUser`, along with the class?

Comment: Check if table1 save operation failed. userId is available iff save operation successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in your model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'userId';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the `userId` from `$table1` in `$table1->userId`, make sure you've the attribute inside the `allUser` model.

And make sure the `user_id` inside the `pMember` model under the `$fillable` with other attributes like :

```
protected $fillable = [ 'addNo', 'addStreet', 'addCity', 'intentToJoin', 'user_id', ...];
```

Comment: You have to discuss with us so we can help, I have suggested things to you, have you checked them? is the error still the same?

Comment: Post the new controller code after the changes you made and the models two in your question, so we could see where we're currently.

Comment: I only change p-member and all user model.(from add protected fillable ) how do I change controller??

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class allUser extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'userId', 'nameWithInitials', 'callingName','email', 'NIC', 'contactNo','password','type'];
}

Comment: Good job, Then you need to add the `userId` to the table when you are defining the `$table1` using  `$table1->userId             = "value you want here"` before save

Comment: userId is primary key in all_user table. It set it as auto increment. How gonna we catch it??

Comment: So try to add `dd( $table1->userId )` just after `$table1->save();` and show me the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179572/discussion-between-sanduniyw-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the `user_id` value is not being sent, it may be null or undefined.

```
$table2->user_id          = $table1->userId; //problem here

$table2->save();
```

above see your last two lines

Before saving, try to `dd()` the `user_id`

like this: `dd($table1->userId)` before saving.

Or

Note: Doing so will avoid errors, but will give you the ability to write without `user_id`

You can let `user_id` in you migrations nullable

example: `$table->string('user_id')->nullable();`

after that run: `php artisan migrate:refresh`